# Como mostrar postagens de uma Fan Page do Facebook em um Site

Tags: api, plugin, facebook

Gostaria de saber qual `Api` ou `Plugin` devo utilizar para disponibilizar em meu site as últimas postagens da minha `FanPage`.

Na verdade eu ainda estou pesquisando para saber se o que quero fazer é possível. O que pretendo fazer é em um site comum, disponibilizar as informações das minhas mídias sociais.

Por exemplo, colocar nessa página as últimas postagens da minha `FanPage` do `facebook`, as últimas postagens do `Twitter`, últimas do `Instagram`. Então comecei com o `Facebook` para saber se é possível fazer esse tipo de coisa e a princípio eu não botei a mão em código e nem conheço muito as `APIs` do `Facebook`.

Comment: Olá Patrick, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O que você já fez? Tem algum exemplo de código? Já utiliza a alguma das APIs do facebook? Sem essas informações, sua pergunta fica muito ampla.

Comment: Por favor, **[edit]e** a pergunta para adicionar informações sobre seu problema ao invés de explicar aqui nos comentários.

Answer (score 3):

Penso que aquilo que procuras é o [Activity Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity), um dos muitos plugIns que o Facebook disponibiliza para que possas apresentar dados da tua página do Facebook no teu web-site.

Não requerer programação nenhuma da tua parte, basta acederes ao link e preencheres o teu endereço. É gerado um código que deverás copiar para o teu site, colocando-o no local onde pretendes que a *Activity* apareça.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este plugin de atividades me atenderia sim, mas pesquisando o que seria o ideal era ter o plugin Embed Post de forma que ele automaticamente pegasse o último post que eu inseri na minha fanpage e adicione ao site, e não como é hoje, pois toda vez que eu criar um novo post eu tenho que pegar o código embed dele, ir no site e alterar.. Ele não é automático.

Comment: @Patrick O _Activity Feed_ do Facebook apresenta os últimos _posts_, claro que, ele carrega os mesmos quando acedes à página... se tens a página aberta quando colocas um _post_ novo no Facebook, precisas actualizar a mesma clicando no botão de actualizar do teu navegador, ou usando a tecla `F5`. Desta forma deverá aparecer o último _post_ adicionado... não precisas de andar sempre a copiar o código.

Comment: O Problema do Activity Feed é que ele aparece apenas o link para a postagem, e eu gostaria de um preview da postagem como este abaixo.

http://static.squarespace.com/static/506ecd35e4b0400133c9194d/t/51ffd583e4b0d7e07cd8d8b0/1375720836863/embedded-facebook-post-embed-facebook-post-example-how-to.PNG

Comment: @Patrick Para esse efeito, deverás utilizar o PlugIn do Facebook [_Embedded Posts_](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts).

Comment: Como havia dito, existe alguma forma de automatizar o Embeded Posts Plugin para que eu adicione a página e ele busque sempre a última postagem desta página? Pois da forma que ele funciona hoje, você deve adicionar o post fixo.

Comment: @Patrick Existe sim, mas deixa-me testar primeiro porque requer uso da API do Facebook. Já agora, estás a usar que linguagem? PHP ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o PHP!